# Use of member access operator on a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I haven't used C in a while, and now i'm trying to go back to it.

My problem is that my code actually works, although I was sure I will get syntax errors. He'res What I want to have:
A dynamic array of polygons, each has a dynamic array of points.

```
struct point{
  int x,y;
};

struct polygon{
  int quantity;
  struct point* point_list;
};
```

I will then initialize an array of polygons:

```
struct polygon* poly_array = (struct polygon*) malloc(sizeof(struct polygon)*num);
```

and also, initialize each polygon's point array:

```
poly_array[i].quantity = points;
poly_array[i].point_list = (struct point*) malloc (sizeof( struct point) *  poly_array[i].quantity);
```

Now, what I thought I was doing, was create arrays of pointers to the object. So, to access inner fields, I would need to use the "->" operator. But no, it works with "direct" access to the fields (short version, without the loop code):

```
poly_array[i].point_list[j].x = i;
poly_array[i].point_list[j].y = j;
```

and also to print:

```
printf ("poly %d: (%d, %d)\n", j, poly_array[i].point_list[j].x, poly_array[i].point_list[j].y);
```

So, to make my question clear, I will ask again: since I'm iterating on pointers to objects, shouldn't I use the `->` operator?

Comment: You are not creating arrays of pointers and not iterating on pointers to objects. Perhaps you meant to, but that's not what actually happens in your code.

Comment: `type->field` is simply an equivilant to `(*type).field`. It is used so you dont have to explicitly dereference a pointer to get to a type inside.

Comment: No you would use polygon ->point_list[i]... the left hand side has to be a pointer , hence the use of arrow symbol to remind you !

Comment: Use a `struct` with a flexible array member. This avoids one indirection and seperate allocation.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `poly_array` is of type `struct polygon*`, so, `poly_array[i]` will be of type `struct polygon`. Thus, you have to use the `.` operator.

same logic applies for `point_list[j]` also.

To elaborate, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.1, *Array subscripting* (*emphasis mine*)

> **syntax**
>
> *`postfix-expression [ expression ]`*
>
> **Constraints**
>
> One of the expressions shall have type *‘‘pointer to complete object type’’*, the other
>   expression shall have integer type, **and the result has type *‘‘type’’*.**

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: so what i have is simply an array that holds actual polygons, yes?

Comment: @yoadw Not really, pointers are not arrays. Concentrate on the data type itself.

Comment: so, if I wanted to have an array of pointers to polygons, how would I need to change my code? (I hope it's not too much to ask, thanks!)

Comment: @yoadw array of pointers to polygons? It should be something like `struct polygon* poly_array[10]` and the `malloc()` will also change, but are you sure that's what you need? (10 is arbitrary anyway...)

Comment: i don't need it for any specific reason, i'm doing it to refresh memory\knowledge regarding C. this is actually a part of question from some old college test, and i'm messing around with the results.
thanks.

Comment: @yoadw You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is referring to the array by index already dereferences the indexed item, so you are correct using dot syntax.

```
poly_array[i].point_list[j].x
```

You could as well use the "->" operator to dereference the item directly without using index operator []. In that case you would use pointer arithmetic.

```
(((poly_array+i)->point_list)+j)->x
```